# jquery - how to prevent form from redirecting after client side validation occurs with invalid data

Tags: jquery, submit, postback, return, preventdefault

I have a repeater on a form and have used jquery to validate the data in the repeater.  Im having trouble preventing the page from redirecting on the client side using jquery.

here is my jquery:

```
function ValidateBid() 
{
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".btnSubmitBid").click(function (evt) {

            var msg = "";
            var bid = $(this).closest('td').find("input"); //this was the fun part

            if (isNaN(bid.val())) {
                msg = "Bid amount allowed in complete dollars only";
            }
            if (bid.val().indexOf('.') >= 0) {
                msg = "Bid amount may only contain numbers";
            }
            if (bid.val() > 999999) {
                msg = "If you want to place a bid for $" + bid.val() + " please contact customer service";
            }

            if (msg.length > 0) {

                $('#dialogText').text(msg);
                $('#dialog').dialog({
                    closeOnEscape: true, modal: true, width: 450, height: 200, title: 'Please correct the errors below:', close: function (event, ui) { $(this).dialog("destroy"); }
                });
                evt.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }

        });
    });

} //ends doc rdy
```

I have tried using return false and evt.preventDefault(); with no luck.

Its getting redirected in the code behind in the repeater_ItemCommand event if the user has not logged in yet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe you should use .submit() instead of .click()

Answer (score 2):

It is not a good idea to have the call to document.ready inside a function. You are binding to the click event of the submit button, what I would do is remove the function wrapper and bind to the submit event of the form itself, that way you just return false when validation finds an error, and if not it will continue with the submission, return true never does any harm if you feel the need:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $("form").submit(function (evt) {
//obv you would need to put the form id or class if you have more than one form on the page

            var msg = "";
            var bid = $(this).closest('td').find("input"); //this was the fun part

            if (isNaN(bid.val())) {
                msg = "Bid amount allowed in complete dollars only";
            }
            if (bid.val().indexOf('.') >= 0) {
                msg = "Bid amount may only contain numbers";
            }
            if (bid.val() > 999999) {
                msg = "If you want to place a bid for $" + bid.val() + " please contact customer service";
            }

            if (msg.length > 0) {

                $('#dialogText').text(msg);
                $('#dialog').dialog({
                    closeOnEscape: true, modal: true, width: 450, height: 200, title: 'Please correct the errors below:', close: function (event, ui) { $(this).dialog("destroy"); }
                });

                return false;
            }
            else {
                return true;
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: In the case of a form submission, you wouldn't want `preventDefault()` at the top - since you want it to perform the default action if the form is valid.

Comment: the call is at the top of the script reference like this.  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    ValidateBid();

Comment: i also tried it on the button.  <asp:Button style="width:100px;height:30px;line-height:20px;"  Visible="true" CssClass="btnSubmitBid"  ID="lbBid" Text="BID" runat="Server" CommandName="makeBid" UseSubmitBehavior="False" ></asp:Button> using the OnClientClick(return ValidateBid()) and had no luck there either

Comment: @ahren of course you are right - I am so used to doing my client side validation on the inputs. Ches187 I am amending my answer now

Comment: ok i took it out from being wrapped in a function and added the evt.preventDefault(); to the top as recommended and it still redirects.  Any other ideas?

Comment: i changed the code binding to bind to the submit event and still no luck.  Would the UseSubmitBehavior="False" have any effect on this?

Comment: My initial ask to move the preventDefault to the top was wrong, now we are using the submit event, remove the preventDefault altogether if you haven't alreadt. If that doesn't work then try UseSubmitBehaviour="true"